# Angular replace pipe operator is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using replace operator in angular but i am getting below error, can anyone please let me know what was the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idantm?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: There's no builtin `replace` pipe in Angular.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no build in pipe named "replace". Here is official documentation https://angular.io/api?type=pipe You have to build your own custom pipe.

Comment: why did you unmark answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom pipe named replace since Angular does not have a pipe in build

```
import {Pipe} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: "replace"}) export default class {
  transform(value: string, replacements: {[key: string]: {}}): string {
    return Object
      .entries(replacements)
      .reduce((result, [key, value]) => result.replace("{{" + key + "}}", value), value);
  }
}
```

Comment: @AluanHaddadThat was a sample, now i modified

Comment: And now it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Try `return Object.entries(replacements).reduce(result, [key, value]) => result.replace("{{" + key + "}}", value), value);`

Comment: a couple questions... 1. is "replacements: {[key: string]: {}}" the same as "replacements: Map<string, any>" ?    2. how is the new pipe called?  somthig like... {{ someVal | repace:  ??? }}